# Create an input range slider with a high range

Tags: website-design, page-layout

I want to create a web page for some visualizations I made using [d3.js](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijy_fC4IbbAhWG0RQKHUUuBjwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fd3js.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3LPzG672wd3APWnSeZucyJ).
I create a map, an heatmap and some other small charts.
In this drawing I show (very schematically) how the created graphs should be positioned on the page (it makes the idea of the size they occupy).

[image]

The visualizations are interactive and the user can choose some parameters using radio buttons, a check box and an input range slider (for select an year).

So, my input range slider look like that:

[image]

In total the user can choose between 37 different years (from 1981 to 2017).
What I wonder is what is the way to make the best (in terms of graphics) this slider. Surely it must:

- it must be long otherwise all the years are too close
- must show the labels with the years so it is clearer in what position they are.

I looked for ideas on the internet and I found [this site](http://bashooka.com/coding/25-amazing-css-range-slider-designs/).
Among those shown, the best (in my case) seems to me this:

[image]

The problem is that I have many years to show (37 not 7 as in the example) so a slider like this would really take up so much space.

Do you have any ideas to propose?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited as a [critique request](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611). As it stands, I think it's a bit too opinion based

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to break down 37 items into sets then subsets...

[image]

I, personally, don't see how you'd get 37 items, any items, clearly defined on a single slider, especially when considering mobile views.

Comment: For the moment, I focus more on desktop viewing. However, of course, in the future it would be better to be able to use it also on mobile devices. Thank you for your idea!

Comment: Mobile first! `:)`